# magento2 order place problem with last name mandatory

Tags: magento-2.1

I am placing an order using api.

In `customer_address_entity` table lastname is blank 
This gives error on payment gateway.

Error is

> ::Please check the shipping address information. Please enter the last
>   name

How can i  resolve this. I don't want last name will mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to make `is_required` for that attribute to 0 in the database table.

Comment: I did this but not get any success.Please tell other thing

Comment: In which table you did that ?

Comment: select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code='lastname'